# Sudoku game serialization issue

Tags: java, serialization, sudoku

I am creating the Sudoku game and I am trying to provide options to save, save as, and open games. I am using JFileChooser to do this. I am able to save (or "save as") but when I try to open a saved file, I get an error. I am new to programming and I'm hoping someone could spot the issue and educate me on how to read in the contents of the Sudoku board when I am saving (as well as how to deal with re-creating the Sudoku board when I open the file). I hear there is an easier way to deal with this using InputStream/OutputStream instead of Reader/Writer...

Here is my code for the inner class that implements this (I don't know if there's a way to post my entire class without exceeding the character limit for this text box.):

EDIT:

```
    // this inner class provides a JMenuBar object at the top of
  // the board
  class MenuAtTop extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener{

    // SudokuMain object we are dealing with
    private SudokuMain main;

    // the "File" menu
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    // the "New Game" option
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    // the "Open" option
    private JMenuItem open;
    // the "Save" option
    private JMenuItem save;
    // the "Save As" option
    private JMenuItem saveAs;
    // the "Reset" option
    private JMenuItem reset;
    // the "Quit" option
    private JMenuItem quit;

    // the ability to choose files
    private JFileChooser choose;

    // the saved file
//    // compiler would not allow "static" keyword
    private File fileSaved = null;

    private Object opener;

    // JDialog object to create a dialog box to prompt
    // user for new game information
    private JDialog createNewWin; 

    /**
     * Constructs MenuAtTop object.
     * 
     * @param m The SudokuMain object to be referred to.
     */
    public MenuAtTop(final SudokuMain m) {

      main = m;

      opener = null;
      choose = new JFileChooser();

      // instantiate and bind to reference
      fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
      add(fileMenu);

      // instantiate and bind to reference
      newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
      newGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
                                                    ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(newGame);
      newGame.addActionListener(this);

      open = new JMenuItem("Open");
      open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(open);
      // add action listener to "Open" option
      open.addActionListener(this);

      save = new JMenuItem("Save");
      save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(save);
      // add action listener to "Save" option
      save.addActionListener(this);

      saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As");
      saveAs.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,
                                                   ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(saveAs);
      // add action listener to "Save As" option
      saveAs.addActionListener(this);

      reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
      reset.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,
                                                  ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(reset);
      // add action listener to "Reset" option
      reset.addActionListener(this);

      quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
      quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,
                                                 ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      fileMenu.add(quit);
      // add action listener to "Quit" option
      quit.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if(e.getSource().equals(newGame)) {

        setEnabled(false);
        // create dialog box prompting for the new board information
        createNewWin = new Dialog1(main, "Create New Board", true);
        // make it visible
        createNewWin.setVisible(true);

        fileSaved = null;

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(open)) {

        int returnVal = choose.showOpenDialog(main.win);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          boolean error = false;
          File openFile = choose.getSelectedFile();

          try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(openFile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            opener = ois.readObject();
            SudokuBase sudoku = (SudokuBoard) opener;
            ois.close();
          } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error opening file.");
            error = true;
          }

          // "opener" reads something and it is of type SudokuBase
          if(opener != null && opener instanceof SudokuBase){

            main.north.remove(main.rowColRegStates);
            main.west.remove(main.symbols);
            main.east.remove(main.view);

            main.view =  new SudokuView((SudokuBase) opener);
            main.rowColRegStates = new ShowStates(main.view);
            main.symbols = new SetSymbols(main.view);

            main.north.add(main.rowColRegStates);
            main.west.add(main.symbols);
            main.east.add(main.view);

            main.win.requestFocus();

            fileSaved = openFile;
          } else {
            if(error) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Incorrect file type.");
            }
          }
        }

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(save)) {

        if(fileSaved == null) {
          saveAsPrompt();
        } else {
          try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileSaved);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            board.writeToStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(board);
            oos.close();
          } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
          }
        }

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(saveAs)) {
        saveAsPrompt();
      } else if(e.getSource().equals(reset)) {

        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main.win, 
                                              "Any player values will" +
                                              " be lost. Proceed?",
                                              "Warning!", 2);
        if(n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
          main.board.reset();
          main.view.repaint();
        }

      } else if(e.getSource().equals(quit)) {
        closePrompt();
      }

    }

    // This method prompts the user to choose a file to save to,
    // and then saves the file.
    private int saveAsPrompt() {
      boolean saveError;
      int rtn = choose.showSaveDialog(main.win);

      if(rtn == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        saveError = false;
        File fileSaveAs = choose.getSelectedFile();
        try {
          board.writeToStream(new FileOutputStream(fileSaveAs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
          saveError = true;
        }

        if(!saveError) {
          fileSaved = fileSaveAs;
        }
      }

      return rtn;

    }

    // This method prompts the user whether they want to save before
    // closing, only if changes occurred.
    private void closePrompt() {
      if(true) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main.win, "Save game?");
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
          int saved = saveAsPrompt();
          if(saved != JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
            main.win.dispose();
          }
        } else if(n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
          main.win.dispose();
        }
      }
      else { // no changes were made
        main.win.dispose();
      }
    }

  }
```

Here's the class that holds the data (it is extended by SudokuBoard):

```
// Allow short name access to following classes
import java.util.Observable;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public abstract class SudokuBase extends Observable {
  // rows per region
  private int rows;
  // columns per region
  private int columns;
  // size of a region (rows * columns)
  private int size;
  // array of each element of entire sudoku board
  private int[] grid;

  // the masked 8-bit "given" value constant
  private static final int GIVEN_MASK = 0x00000100;
  // the bitwise complement of the masked "given" constant,
  // which produces an unmasked constant
  private static final int GIVEN_UNMASK = ~ GIVEN_MASK;

  /** 
   * Enumerated type to store constants that indicate the "State" of
   * a specified row, column, or region.
   */
  public enum State {COMPLETE, INCOMPLETE, ERROR};

  /**
   * Constructs SudokuBase object.
   * 
   * @param layoutRows The number of rows per region.
   * @param layoutColumns The number of columns per region.
   */
  public SudokuBase(int layoutRows, int layoutColumns) {
    rows = layoutRows;
    columns = layoutColumns;
    size = columns * rows;
    grid = new int[size*size];
  }

  /**
   * Gets the number of rows per region.
   * 
   * @return The rows per region.
   */
  public int getRowsPerRegion() {
    return rows;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the number of columns per region.
   * 
   * @return The columns per region.
   */
  public int getColumnsPerRegion() {
    return columns;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the size of the region (rows * columns).
   * 
   * @return The size of the region.
   */
  public int getBoardSize() {
    return size;
  }

  // gets the index of the specified row and column for the grid
  private int getIndex(int row, int col) {
    // handle invalid arguments
    if(row < 0 || row >= size || col < 0 || col >= size) {
      String msg = "Error in location";
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }
    return row * size + col;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the element at the specified row
   * and column on the grid.
   * 
   * @param row The specified row.
   * @param col The specified column.
   * @return The value of the element at the specified row and column.
   */
  public int getValue(int row, int col) {
    return grid[getIndex(row, col)] & GIVEN_UNMASK;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the desired value at the specified row and column.
   * 
   * @param row The specified row.
   * @param col The specified column.
   * @param value The specified value to be set.
   */
  public void setValue(int row, int col, int value) {
    // handle invalid argument
    if(value < 0 || value > size) {
      String msg = "Value out of range: " + value;
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }
    // handle attempt to set a value for a "given" location
    if(isGiven(row, col)) {
      String msg = "Cannot set given location: " + row + ", " + col;
      throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
    }
    grid[getIndex(row, col)] = value;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
  }

  /**
   * This method checks the status of the "givens" bit.
   * 
   * @param row The specified row.
   * @param col The specified column.
   * @return Whether or not the specified location is a "given" value.
   */
  public boolean isGiven(int row, int col) {
    return (grid[getIndex(row, col)] & GIVEN_MASK) == GIVEN_MASK;
  }

  /**
   * This method sets non-zero values on the Sudoku board with the
   * "givens" bit.
   */
  public void fixGivens() {
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
      if(grid[i] != 0)
      grid[i] |= GIVEN_MASK;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
  }

  /**
   * This abstract method gets the "State" (COMPLETE, INCOMPLETE,
   * or ERROR) of the specified row.
   *
   * @param n The specified row.
   * @return The "State" of the row.
   */
  public abstract State getRowState(int n);

  /**
   * This abstract method gets the "State" (COMPLETE, INCOMPLETE,
   * or ERROR) of the specified column.
   *
   * @param n The specified column.
   * @return The "State" of the column.
   */
  public abstract State getColumnState(int n);

  /**
   * This abstract method gets the "State" (COMPLETE, INCOMPLETE,
   * or ERROR) of the specified region.
   *
   * @param n The specified region.
   * @return The "State" of the region.
   */
  public abstract State getRegionState(int n);

  /**
   * Represents the Sudoku board as a grid of appropriate characters.
   * 
   * @return The string representation of the Sudoku board.
   */
  public String toString() {
    String board = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < size; j ++)
        board += charFor(i, j) + " ";
      board += "\n";
    }
    return board;
  }

  // this method provides a character for all possible values encountered on the
  // Sudoku board, to be utilized in "toString()"
  private String charFor(int i, int j) {
    int v = getValue(i, j);
    // negative value (invalid)
    if(v < 0) {
      return "?";
    } else if(v == 0) {  // blank or zero value
      return ".";
    } else if(v < 36) {  // value from 1 to (size * size)
      return Character.toString(Character.forDigit(v, 36)).toUpperCase();
    } else {  // non-numeric input or v >= size * size (both invalid)
      return "?";
    }
  }

  /**
   * This method reads from an input stream.
   * 
   * @param is The input stream to read from.
   */
  protected void readFromStream(InputStream is) {
  }

  /**
   * This method writes to an output stream.
   * 
   * @param os The output stream to write to.
   */
    protected void writeToStream(OutputStream os) {
    try {
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
     oos.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
    }

  }

  /**
   * Gets the "raw" value directly, not having checked whether there is an
   * unfixed error message.
   * 
   * @param row The row where the raw value is located.
   * @param col The column where the raw value is located.
   * @return The raw value.
   */
  protected int getRawValue(int row, int col) {
    return grid[getIndex(row, col)];
  }

  /**
   * Sets the raw value directly, not having checked whether there is an
   * unfixed error message.
   * 
   * @param row The row where the raw value is to be located.
   * @param col The column where the raw value is to be located.
   */
  protected void setRawValue(int row, int col, int value) {
    grid[getIndex(row, col)] = value;
  }

  protected void reset() {
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
        if(!isGiven(row, col)) {
          grid[getIndex(row, col)] = 0;
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I cannot give a full answer and I do not want to browse the full source code. But a few pointers for you to find some solution:

Never catch Exceptions like that while developing an application:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main.win, "Error saving file.");
      saveError = true;
}
```

With this, you completely loose the chance to detect errors. At least add the following line to your exception handling:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Normally you would log the exception and so on, but with that you see the source of your error at the console. Better than nothing.

To your more specific problem:
You seem to write an Object to a file holding all the configuration. In your read method something goes wrong. Probably you do not read the same object as you write or something like that. Hard to say without any code. Try to get the exception stack trace and figure out what the problem is. If you cannot figure it out, edit your question with more specific information and I will try to give better directions.

EDIT:
Here is a small example showing serialization of objects for a Sudoku like game:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class SerializationExample {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final File target = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmp"), "mySerializedObject.txt");

    Map<Integer, Integer> initialState = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    initialState.put(1, 1);
    initialState.put(21, 3);
    // ...

    GameState state = new GameState(10, initialState);
    state.setField(2, 2);
    state.setField(3, 8);
    System.out.println("Game state before writing to file: " + state);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target));
    out.writeObject(state);
    out.close();

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(target));
    Object gameStateReadFromFile = in.readObject();
    GameState readGameState = (GameState)gameStateReadFromFile;
    System.out.println("Read from file: " + readGameState);
  }

  private static class GameState implements Serializable {
    private int[] fields;

    private int boardSize;

    private int[] fixedFields;

    public GameState(int boardSize, Map<Integer, Integer> initialState) {
      this.boardSize = boardSize;
      this.fields = new int[boardSize * boardSize];
      this.fixedFields = new int[this.fields.length];

      for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : initialState.entrySet()) {
        this.fixedFields[entry.getKey()] = entry.getValue();
      }
    }

    public void setField(int index, int value) {
      this.fields[index] = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      builder.append("\nFixed fields: ");
      appendArray(builder, this.fixedFields);
      builder.append("\nSet fields: ");
      appendArray(builder, this.fields);
      return builder.toString();
    }

    private void appendArray(StringBuilder builder, int[] fieldArray) {
      for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; ++i) {
        if (fieldArray[i] != 0) {
          builder.append("row ").append(i / this.boardSize).append(" column ").append(i % this.boardSize)
              .append(" has value ")
              .append(fieldArray[i]).append(",");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So for the Sudoku game I have int values that I need to save. Since some of the values are given (set before the game) and some are playable values (can be changed), I was planning to go through the grid of values and determine which are "given" values (I have a method that does that) and store them. Then I would go through the grid again and store the playable values.

Comment: You can do that in many ways. Your source code however indicates, that you are storing an object and want to read an object later.
Following this strategy it would be a good idea to have a object representing your game state (maybe the sudoku board with the grid plus the information which values are given). If this object (and all contained objects) implement the Serializable interface, you should be golden.

Comment: So for the Sudoku game I have int values that I need to save and restore. Since some of the values are given (set before the game) and some are playable values (can be changed), I was planning to go through the grid of values and determine which are "given" values (I have a method that does that) and store the row, column, and value information for each. Then I would go through the grid again and store the row, column, and value information for the playable values. When I open a file, I want to have the saved board restored. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to go about doing that?

Comment: I guess I pressed enter a little early before. Do you think you could create a simple example that is similar to what I am trying to do? I am trying to understand how to deal with the object (SudokuBoard) and how to extract the necessary information.

Comment: Added an example for Serialization to my answer. I guess you can adapt this to your Application

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps. However, I still run into the same error in my try-catch statement. ("Error opening file." and then: "Incorrrect file type."). Am I forgetting something?

Comment: I edited my initial question above to include my updated code and the class where the data is stored.

Comment: This is the result of the printStackTrace() method call:

java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at SudokuMain$MenuAtTop.actionPerformed(SudokuMain.java:575)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)...

Comment: Hmm, looks like you actually do not write your object to the file. Have a look at your writeToStream method you posted. There is implementation missing.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm stuck on how to implement the method though.
I edited the initial question again with an implemented writeToStream method (that does not work).

Comment: I looked through tutorials and the API documentation, and I still get the same error:  "Error opening file." and then: "Incorrrect file type." I could really use some help...